# paypal integration in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce

hi i'm new to the web development.I just created a online shop in which all things finally i want to add some mechanism by which i redirect my customer to paypal site and pay then redirect to my site.please help me.

Comment: Read the f. manual ! There are all there, and there are a lot of examples also in Paypal.

Comment: Completely agree with @Aristos! Will suggest to start from Paypal site: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_overview

Comment: simplest way i found


<a href=" https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=YourPaymentEmailAtPayPal&item_name=YourItemName&item_number=YourItemNumber&amount=PriceNoDollarSign">

</a>

Answer (score 0):

To help you with the idea.

**The idea is that you collect all your order informations to a page, places this informations in a form using hidden input controls, and you post them to paypal.**

This informations iclude the url that your customer can return if he like to cancel, return when its complete, the cost, your email, your customer email, and many other parametres that you can read them on the manual.

Download the sdk here:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks

And there are also the documents here

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_documentation

Also you can find a sample code, and other.

Answer (score 0):

the quickest and simplest way to integrate paypal

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
?cmd=_xclick&business=MyEmail
&item_name=Widget
&amount=29.00
&undefined_quantity=1
&currency_code=USD">
```